# CSS white-space: nowrap; not respecting max-width

Tags: css

**CSS  white-space: nowrap; not respecting max-width**

Reproduce:

Run the below code

White-space is causing this issue where it increase the width of the right container and igroring the max-width of parent container

Current result: Width of right excees the max- width: 1680px;

Expected Result : Width should not exceed max-width: 1680px;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>test application</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: red;
        }
        
       div{
          box-sizing: border-box;
         }


        .container {
            align-items: stretch;
            max-width: 1680px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .container .left {
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
            width: 18em;
            padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
            position: relative;
            color: white;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-right: 2em;
            min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }

        .container .right {
            background-color: green;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0em 3em 3em 3em;
            flex: 1
        }


        .b2 {
            width: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .abc {
            display: inline-flex;
            /* width: 1640px; */
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">left </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="b2">
                <div class="abc">
                    rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
                </div>
                <div class="abc">
                    rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: min-width:0 to .right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `white-spacing` relies on white-spaces to break the text apart. **Since you don't have any, the text will not break onto the new line.**

There are multiple ways to deal with this.

For example you could set `overflow-wrap: anywhere` and `word-wrap: normal` to the `.abc` selector. But this will also break whole-words apart ignoring standard syllable-based word wrapping.

You could also cut out the excess by forcefully setting `overflow: hidden`, `white-space: nowrap` together with a `max-width` and maybe `text-overflow: ellipsis`. But this will actually hide the information.

Caveat: The `overflow-wrap: anywhere` is unfortunately not supported by Safari.

It depends on what you want to achieve.

**Example with 'overflow-wrap: anywhere'**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test application</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    div {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container {
      align-items: stretch;
      max-width: 1680px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    
    .container .left {
      background-color: blue;
      display: flex;
      width: 18em;
      padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 2em;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    
    .container .right {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0em 3em 3em 3em;
      flex: 1
    }
    
    .b2 {
      width: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .abc {
      display: inline-flex;
      overflow-wrap: anywhere;
      white-space: normal;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">left </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="b2">
        <div class="abc">
          rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
        </div>
        <div class="abc">
          rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Example with 'text-overflow: ellipsis'**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test application</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    div {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container {
      align-items: stretch;
      max-width: 1680px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    
    .container .left {
      background-color: blue;
      display: flex;
      width: 18em;
      padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 2em;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    
    .container .right {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0em 3em 3em 3em;
      flex: 1
    }
    
    .b2 {
      width: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .abc {
      display: block;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 100ch;
      /* 100 characters max */
      max-width: 1000px;
      /* 1000px max */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">left </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="b2">
        <div class="abc">
          rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
        </div>
        <div class="abc">
          rightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightrightright
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```